# Take a screenshot of a web page with firefox webextension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I need write webextension that can take screenshot and save it on hard drive (better in folder i specify) can some one share with me peace of code or point to good tutorial about this?

Comment: Why don't you use the in-built app of the operating system?

Comment: Since you asked firefox specific, I have posted a [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/) for your purpose. But you can always substitute it with in built commands/applications of the operating system.

Comment: I better update my question, i actually need write this webextension because i need screenshot not of whole page, but only part of it, then i need to save it in specific folder, of course i can do it manually, using system builtin option, but if i need make 100 screenshots it will be very tedious to do

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a feature that [takes screenshots](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots). If this is what you are looking for.

Another option would be to print that whole page and save it as a pdf to your drive.